# ActiveRecord::Base.transaction with Rails .save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

It is my understanding that wrapping `.save!` in   `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` will make sure all the models (User, Profile, and Setting) to save together or none at all.

However, I was also told that including .save! with all the models.save! methods will also do that.  So essentially, both version 1 and 2 are the same.  I have a feeling I am wrong, so what is the difference?

Thank you

#### Version 1

```
def save
  if valid?
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      User.save!
      Profile.save!
      Setting.save!
    end
  else
    false
  end
end
```

#### Version 2

```
def save
  if valid?
      User.save!
      Profile.save!
      Setting.save!      
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Reference: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 5):

In the first case if any of save! statement fails then all the previous saved models will be rolled back. For ex:
If `setting.save!` fails then `setting.save!`, `user.save!` and `profile.save!` will be rolled back.

But in second case if any save! statement fails then it will only rollback that statement and it will also raise an exception. For ex:
If `setting.save!` fails then only `setting.save!` will be rolled back.

Both statements will work same only in 1 case when the first statement fails 'user.save!' as exception will be raised and in second case subsequent statement will not be executed

The difference between `save` and `save!` is that the latter will raise an exception but both will not save the value of object to table if validations fail.